# Firebase unresolved supertype with Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I'm experiencing a problem in my project that uses Firebase core and messaging v11.4.2.

The gradle sync works perfectly but then I get this error when compiling:

> e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>
> class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctr, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzee
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ‘:app:compileDebugKotlin’.
>     Compilation error. See log for more details

I've tried both with Kotlin version 1.1.51 and 1.2.0-beta-88; Gradle plugins v2.3.3 and 3.0.0

Any help is welcomed, thanks a lot!

This is how I've configured the project:

**app build.gradle**

```
// tried adding and removing the -kapt and -android-extensions. Didn't help.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

debug {

/// added this to be sure the class was not being left out
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
useProguard false
}

...

dependencies {

 // Firebase Core
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
// Firebase Cloud Messaging
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
}

...

// Keep this as the last line or the build will fail
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*** project build.gradle ***

```
buildscript {
    // App
    ext.compileSdkVersion = 26
    ext.minSdkVersion = 18
    ext.buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'
    ext.targetSdkVersion = 26

    // Kotlin beta, stable version doesn't compile either
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0-beta-88'

    // Android
    ext.androidSupportVersion = '26.1.0'
    //TODO: implement LifecycleOwner interface from Architecture Components.
   ext.lifecycleVersion = '1.0.0-beta2'

    // Architecture, RxJava, Injection
    ext.daggerVersion = '2.11'
    ext.butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
    ext.rxJavaVersion = '2.1.0'
    ext.rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'

    // Google/Firebase Cloud Message
    ext.firebaseVersion = '11.4.2'

    // Libraries shared between modules (TODO)
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }     // Google Maven Repository

    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.2'} // Kotlin beta
}

dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'  // google-services plugin
     //// tried this too: classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'            
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.2'}
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

}
```

Comment: can you try "api" in place of "implementation" in dependencies like
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"

Comment: Tried switching implementation for api for firebase only and it didn't work. Then tried switching everything to api and it also failed to build. Any further ideas? @SangeetSuresh

Comment: can you confirm in gradle-wrapper.properties that 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
is used

Comment: I confirm that's the gradle being used

Comment: @SangeetSuresh thank you for your help, finally solved the problem. The answer was rather silly and is written down here:

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was an incompatible version of the Google Wallet library, being implemented by another dependency of the project and conflicting with the one imported by the com.google.gms.google-services plugin.

For some reason gradle didn't state this problem and I had to go through the code until I found the place where Wallet was trying to access a class that was successfully importing but at the same time it couldn't be found.

Simply by updating the version in the other module everything was fixed :)